# How can i get ASP.Net Grid Element using Javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, gridview

I am using a Grid View in asp.net, i want to get Element on clicking a grid, how can i do so?
A grid has a column id, name, warp, weft, etc, i want to pick the selected cell data using Javascript, let me know.

Please help...

Regards
Atif

Comment: Do you want to get on Click button that is inside grdiview ?

Comment: yes, i want if you click any row of a grid view, it should fetch element's collection. ID, Name, Warp, Weft

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To track which row button is clicked, you have to set the `row Index` as a parameter to a JS function like...

```
 protected void grdForecast_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType ==DataControlRowType.DataRow )
    {
        ((Button)e.Row.FindControl("buttonId")).Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:update(" + (e.Row.RowIndex ) + ");");
    }
}
```

And then in JavaScript:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function update(ri) {
        var grd = document.getElementById('<%= GridView1.ClientID %>');
        SecondCellValue = grd.rows[ri].cells[1].childNodes[0].value
        ThirdCellValue = grd.rows[ri].cells[2].childNodes[0].value
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I dont want to click on button, i want whole row to be clickable, is it possible?

Comment: this js does not work, returns undefined if we alert secondcellvalue or thirdcellvalue

Comment: Can you put childNodes[1].value and try ?

Comment: this was a simple solution document.getElementById('ContractGrid').rows[ri].cells[1].innerHTML   i dont know why you were going into so much deep.

Comment: accepting your answer, it was wrong but it helped me towards right, thanks.

Comment: yah, you are right, I was not dig in the code, but that's way I told in you anwer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a control inside the cell that you can reference?  If not, then you can create a hidden control.  Then you can write out the control's client id to the client side in the PreRender event handler via ScriptManager.  And you can then get a hold of that element by id and find other content inside that parent cell.

Alternatively, you can use jquery to handle cell click events...

```
$('#myTable td').click(function () {
  alert($(this).html());
});
```